# Extract address data / Query point in administrative boundary

Tags: postgis, polygon, point, query, address

I try to create a DB in postgreSQL with all the postal adress data for a specific country.

Actually I have this table full of data:

> id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('plz_id_seq'::regclass),
>     country_code character varying(20),
>     postal_code character varying(20),
>     city_name character varying(180),
>     state_name character varying(180),
>     state_code character varying(20),
>     community_name character varying(180),
>     community_code character varying(20),
>     latitude double precision,
>     longitude double precision,
>     CONSTRAINT plz_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)

The next step should be, to create a new table with the streets and housenumbers and link it to the right postal code area. For this I imported the specific OSM data into postgis with osm2pgsql and the hstore option.

Where Im now stuck, is the query to find the OSM postal_code area/polygon that fits to my plz data.

I tried this query, but get nothing back:

> SELECT * FROM planet_osm_polygon 
>   WHERE boundary='postal_code' AND ST_CONTAINS(way, ST_PointFromText('POINT(48 7.85)', 900913));

Where ist my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
...ST_PointFromText('POINT(48 7.85)', 900913))...
```

I'm assuming that you meant [this place](https://www.google.pl/maps/place/48%C2%B000%2700.0%22N+7%C2%B051%2700.0%22E/@48,7.85,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) (48°N 7.85°E), so the coordinates are geographical (EPSG:4326), not Web Mercator (EPSG:900913). In the [place you gave](https://www.google.pl/maps/place/0%C2%B000%2701.6%22N+7%C2%B003%2706.4%22E/@0.8765567,4.954073,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) to function (48 7.85 in EPSG:900913 = 0.0004°N 7.0517°E in EPSG:4326) could not be any of postal_code boundaries, cause it's middle of Gulf of Guinea.

Try to change this piece of query to:

```
...ST_Transform(ST_PointFromText('POINT(48 7.85)', 4326),900913)...
```

Of course if your data in planet_osm_polygon table is in EPSG:900913 projection